# How to trigger processing of yaml files in local build?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working on a GAE/Java app, and today I read about using app.yaml, queue.yaml, etc. to more simply specify values to go into web.xml, appengine-web.xml.  Previously I have been building those .xml files myself by hand.

So, I created an app.yaml and a queue.yaml.  Now, how do I hook them into my build (both Eclipse and maven) so that they generate the correct .xml output files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out how this works.  In the local development environment, `app.yaml` is processed to generate `web.xml` and `appengine-web.xml` when you run `dev_appserver.sh` (or .cmd on Windows).  Thus it isn't really necessary to generate them during the build.

The generation of these files for production use is performed when you execute `appconfg.sh/.cmd`.

Comment: note: I haven't figured out how to generate queue.xml from queue.yaml locally.  Neither `dev_appserver` nor `appcfg` seem to do it.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135861/queue-yaml-not-working-in-app-engine-development) question for that, specifically.