# queue.yaml not working in App engine (development)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm trying to use "queue.yaml" to define queues in a Google App Engine app (Java version).

```
 queue:
 - name: default
   rate: 5/s
 - name: availableTicketsAlert
   rate: 5/s
 - name: billingReminder
   rate: 5/s
 - name: cseIndexing
   mode: pull
```

When I try to see if they've been created correctly in this URL: /_ah/admin/taskqueue, I only see "default" queue.

Instead, If I try to create the using with the XML file all works correctly (queue.xml):

```
<queue-entries>
<queue>
    <name>default</name>
    <rate>5/s</rate>
</queue>
<queue>
    <name>availableTicketsAlert</name>
    <rate>5/s</rate>
</queue>
<queue>
    <name>billingReminder</name>
    <rate>5/s</rate>
</queue>
</queue-entries>
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Do I have to update them manually with: appcfg.py update_queues myapp/ or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: if you figure this out, please post an answer here.  I've got the same problem.

Comment: I haven't found anything yet... I think that nobody is using this! =( =(

Comment: Here it is 9 months later.  Did anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: May or may not be related to your problem but when I change settings in my queue.yaml such as the rate or the bucket size, they aren't reflected in the proper queue.