# How to generate web.xml and appengine-web.xml from app.yaml using maven?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

How do I generate the web.xml and appengine-web.xml when using the gcloud/mvn tools on the command line?  This question below was correct up until recently when the tools changed.  Now I'm not sure how to do this with the new set of gcloud/mvn commands:

[How to trigger processing of yaml files in local build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742112/how-to-trigger-processing-of-yaml-files-in-local-build)

Here is the basic setup:

1. I used maven to generate the hello-endpoints example/sample app
2. I'm trying to use the app.yaml via [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml) Which states:

> One of the benefits of using app.yaml is that it automatically
>   generates web.xml and appengine-web.xml for you. It overwrites any
>   content you may have written in those files.

Yet, I don't see that as occurring when I use the mvn/gcloud tools, only when using Eclipse. Once I remove the web.xml and the appengine-web.xml, I get errors in the following commands:

- "mvn clean install"
- "mvn appengine:devserver"
- "mvn appengine:update"

all produce the below error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) on project myproj: The specified web.xml file '/Users/cade/Documents/workspace-gcloud/myproj/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/web.xml' does not exist -> [Help 1]

Now, if I go back into Eclipse where I have imported the maven project and setup the local dev engine according to [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse), I can see when I select "Debug On Server" I can see the new web.xml and appengine-web.xml.

- /Users/cade/Documents/workspace-gcloud/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/myproj/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
- /Users/cade/Documents/workspace-gcloud/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/myproj/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

Obviously I could just copy those two files over to their expected location, but that would be silly.  I'd love to know the corrected answer and not the hack-ish one :D

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702721/is-there-a-mandatory-requirement-to-switch-app-yaml (the answer being that there's a new maven plugin).

Comment: Ok, i'm digging hard, but totally lost now :D but I think I'm close.  I followed those steps listed (updating my pom) but that post is talking about xml --> yaml.  I'm talking about yaml --> xml. Also where does this mystery app.yaml live? project root? or WEB-INF?